# Unable to store an UIImage in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I am trying to store a `UIImage` in an `NSMutableArray` but it doesn t work, here is the line I am using:

```
[images addObject:QRImage];
```

There are no compilation errors, but when I debug the app I see that the `NSMutableArray` has 0 objects. i.e. the image was not added.

Comment: Provide more code..thank you.

Comment: Is your `NSMutableArray` allocated?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you trying to add the QRImage class? At a minimum you suffer from horrible instance names.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted NSArrays and Co are not part of the language, but the cocoa(-touch) framework. please leave the tag.

Comment: There is not enough info here. In order to even form an educated guess, we'd need to know a) the context in which this code is supposed to be run, and b) how and in what context you are measuring the length of the array.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Sorry. I've made a mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `NSMutableArray` is not properly initialized. Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// ...
[images addObject:QRImage];
```

Comment: the NSMutableArray is a global variable I tried to put images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in the view didLoad but not working ...

Comment: I could look at your code, if you are willing to post the section that initializes your NSMutableArray. Maybe you 'reinitialize' the array and thus clear it? Or maybe you (inadvertently) clear it by some other means?